# How to extract text in-between 2 different closed html tags that are not inside the tags?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

On a web-page with many b tags with the same class names I want to extract the text between 2 different closed html 'b' tags specifically these b tags

```html
 <b style="display:block">Print Method:</b>
 "
                                On-demand inkjet (piezoelectric)"
<b style="display:block">Minimum Ink Droplet Volume:</b>
```

I tried to use the beautiful soup library to get the data by creating a table, using `findALL`.

```
b.text
```

It prints all the text from all the b tags is there anyway I can get only the text in between those tags.

[Here's](https://www.epson.co.in/For-Home/Printers/EcoTank-Printers/EcoTank-L1110-Single-function-InkTank-Printer/p/C11CG89504) the web-site where i'm getting the HTML from.

Comment: Can you show a bigger example of the HTML so we can diffrentiate? Can you show more of what you tried with `findAll`?

Comment: would regex be an option at all?

Comment: @S.L. No, regex is *never* an option when it comes to processing HTML.

Comment: interesting, could you elaborate why?

Comment: Just post a little more complete HTML, or the page URL that you're scraping. Give people something to work with. Many people will visit this question in the future. Their HTML structure might be different than yours. So it's best to keep the question as general as possible.

Comment: I'm getting the html from [this](https://www.epson.co.in/For-Home/Printers/EcoTank-Printers/EcoTank-L1110-Single-function-InkTank-Printer/p/C11CG89504) website

Comment: @OferSadan so i used soup.find to create a table containing all the tags i need and then used findALL in a loop to find the div tag with the class text-row like so        
**for row in table.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'text-row'}):**   and then i print row.b.text or row.text but i only want the text after that b tag that contains the text which says "Print Method:" which is what i posted i need to print the print method given but it isn't enclosed in any tag so i don't know to get just that any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much easier way for the example you show. Use :contains with bs4 4.7.1+

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.epson.co.in/For-Home/Printers/EcoTank-Printers/EcoTank-L1110-Single-function-InkTank-Printer/p/C11CG89504')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
soup.select_one('b:contains("Print Method:")').next_sibling.strip()
```

You could also have done:

```
print(soup.select_one('.product-classifications b:has(+b)').next_sibling.strip())
```

Comment: This works much better and is a much more optimized solution. Thanks mate.

Comment: If this code throws any warning just replace 'lxml' with 'html5lib'.

Answer (score 2):

See below (Note that the code is not very efficient since it scans every entry in the document)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = ''' <b style="display:block">Print Method:</b>
 "
                                On-demand inkjet (piezoelectric)"
<b style="display:block">Minimum Ink Droplet Volume:</b>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
idx_lst = []
data_idx = -1
for idx, entry in enumerate(soup.contents):
    if entry.name == 'b':
        idx_lst.append(idx)
        if len(idx_lst) == 2:
            if idx_lst[1] - idx_lst[0] == 2:
                data_idx = idx_lst[0] + 1
                break
            else:
                idx_lst = []

if data_idx != -1:
    print(soup.contents[data_idx])
```

output

```
 "
                                On-demand inkjet (piezoelectric)"
```

The code below handles the real HTML

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.epson.co.in/For-Home/Printers/EcoTank-Printers/EcoTank-L1110-Single-function-InkTank-Printer/p/C11CG89504'

findings = set()
r = requests.get(URL)
if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    idx_lst = []
    data_idx = -1
    b_lst = soup.find_all('b', style='display:block')
    for entry in b_lst:
        for idx, x in enumerate(entry.parent.contents):
            if x.name == 'b' and idx not in idx_lst:
                idx_lst.append(idx)
            if len(idx_lst) == 2:
                if idx_lst[1] - idx_lst[0] == 2 or idx_lst[1] - idx_lst[0] == 3:
                    data_idx = idx_lst[0] + 1
                    findings.add(entry.parent.contents[data_idx].strip())
                    idx_lst = []
                else:
                    idx_lst = []

for idx, p in enumerate(findings, 1):
    print('{}) {}'.format(idx, p))
```

output

```
1) 215.9 x 1200 mm (8.5 x 47.24")
2) 1
3) ESC / P-R
4) 5760 x 1440 dpi (with Variable-Sized Droplet Technology)
5) Friction feed
6) Sound Power Level (Black / Colour): 6.6 B(A) / 6.3 B(A)
7) 180 nozzles Black, 59 nozzles per colour (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow)
8) On-demand inkjet (piezoelectric)
9) Bi-directional printing
10) Up to 33 ppm / 15 ppm
11) Legal, Indian-Legal (215 x 345 mm), 8.5 x 13", Letter, A4, 16K (195 x 270 mm), B5, A5, B6, A6, Hagaki (100 x 148 mm), 5 x 7", 4 x 6", Envelopes: #10, DL, C6
12) 3 pl
```

Comment: You better post the real HTML so we can adopt the code to the actual markup.

Comment: Is there any we can do this when there are a lot of tags that are similar to that?

Comment: @dhanushuttarkar Upload a real HTML so we can test this code against it. Did you test the code? Did it work for you?

Comment: It works but not when you get all the tags in the html document unfortunately. I have edited the question to display the link to the page i'm getting the html from in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like that is a bit more readable. Filter simply with the attributes and extract the text.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
id_soup = BeautifulSoup('<b style="my id">  tralala </b>')

if id_soup.b['style']=='my id':
      print(id_soup.text )
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: sorry but i need to get the code from between 2 closed tags that are not enclosed within any tags. In the code you provided "tralala" is enclosed within the b tag, In the html i provided the text exists not within the b tag but outside it. But thanks anyways.